# $S^1 \times D^2$ does not retract to $S^1 \times S^1$ (it's boundary)

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to show what is stated above. I know that if there is such a retraction, there is an injective map $i_* : \pi_1(S^1 \times S^1) \rightarrow \pi_1(S^1 \times D^2)$ induced by the inclusion. I have also have that $\pi_1(S^1 \times D^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_1(S^1 \times S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$. How would I show that the map is not injective (given they have the same cardinality).

Comment: It is not only a function but a group morphism, and it is not only injective but it is a split group injection. So what can you say about a tentative *split group injection* $\mathbb Z^2\longrightarrow \mathbb Z$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Why worry about splitness?

Comment: We have never mentioned split group injections

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Probably not that relevant here, but it never hurts to know what is made available to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no injective group morphism $i : \mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb Z$. If $i$ were such a map, consider $i(1,0) = n$ and $i(0,1) = m$. Since $(0,1)\neq (1,0)$ are nonzero, we have that $m\neq n$ are both nonzero. But then $mn = i(m,0) = i(0,n)$, which cannot be.

Comment: (Another way is to note $\mathbb Q\otimes i$ cannot be injective, since its a $\mathbb Q$-linear map $\mathbb Q^2\to\mathbb Q$.)

Answer (score 1):

If you had such a retraction, then the composition $S^1\times S^1\to S^1\times D^2\to S^1\times S^1$ would be the identity.

Taking $\pi_1$ of these maps, we have $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}\times 0\to \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, which should compose to the identity. But observe that under these maps, $(0,m)$ gets sent to $(0,0)$ since $\pi_1$ preserves products. Homomorphisms send identity to identity, so this is sent to $(0,0).$ So this composition cannot be the identity map. Hence there is no retract.

Comment: You never proved the map induced on fundamental groups is the projection, though.

Comment: Why should $(0,m)$ go to zero?

Comment: Hm yes, perhaps it's enough to just mention that $\pi_1$ preserves products.